# How to inherit class and call a parent constructor?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, super

I created a class:

```
class Human {
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    greet(){
        alert(this.name);
    }
}
```

It works fine. However when I try to inherit from that class, I have an error

```
class Person extends Human{
    constructor(name, age){
        super.constructor(name);
        this.age = age;
    }
    greet(){
        super.greet(this.name + this.age);
    }
}

var no = new Person("Brent", 65);
```

I have such error - *`this` used uninitialized in Person class constructor*.

How can I inherit properly, so that it alerts both age and name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call the parent constructor, you need to use [`super(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#Using_super_in_classes) not `super.constructor(…)`. This special `super` call will initialise the `this` keyword in the [`extend`ing class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Sub_classing_with_extends) with the instance.

Comment: I watched video on youtube where guy was using super.constructor
https://imgur.com/a/akj3v
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4IMGJqot-U

Comment: This same answer is provided in the comments of that YouTube video, don't call `super.constructor(...)` just use `super(...)`. This same problem with the same solution is also provided multiple times in that video. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Comment: @kilogram The video is quite wrong apparently. As the speaker mentioned, he "*figured this out on his own*" (given that he read some other tutorials that had it even worse). Using `super.constructor` might actually have worked with some older transpilers (being equivalent to the ES5 `call` pattern), it does not work in ES6.

Answer (score 1):

you just call `super()` in your constructor.